# Organising Data,Keys and Index for Quick analaysis of Large Data Set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm hoping you can make suggestions about the best way to quickly analyse a data set. All the tables and two possible queries are in the SQL Fiddle here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/22e8f4/1

I have inherited a database of pupil attainment.

The attainment table itself (Benchmark_Assess) currently has 4.5 million rows in it referenced by a pupil id, pupil year group and subject. Each pupil has a number of rows (one per subject).

I also have two tables with pupil contextual data (e.g. gender) in it.

One table (Pupil_Context) has a number of rows for each pupil detailing which groups they are in. The second table (pupils) has one row per a pupil with a number of flags in it identifying the groups the pupil is in.

My analysis is around, for instance, how many male pupils in year 1 got an attainment grade of 3. Clearly there are two ways of doing this depending on which of the pupil contextual data tables I use. The fiddle has two queries which show this.

Can anybody suggest which of the two queries is best, if they can be improved, and which keys and indexes will help make it run as quickly as possible. If it's important this is an SQL Server database.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You have a real problem with your data model if the same data is being stored *in different ways* in different tables.  That makes it really hard to even tell if the data is consistent.

Comment: I agree, unfortunately it's inherited, I'm open to suggestions about how it should be organised!

Comment: What is your actual question here? The only thing you appear to "ask" is for suggestions, which isn't what [so] is for. Such questions tend to invite discussion and opinionated answers, however, [so] is a Q&A website, not a discussion forum. If you are looking to discuss changes to your database, you're be better off on a community that does allow conversations.

Comment: Sorry if the question wasn't clear. I want to know if there is a more efficient query than the two I have offered and what keys and indexes will speed up any query.

Comment: No one knows your data model. Names like IND and PUPIL_CONTEXT mean nothing to the outsider. Names that contain ID imply relationships and uniqueness. Part of this process of understanding your model is providing or identifying the primary, natural, and unique keys. Your sample data is conveniently "not duplicated" - something that can and likely will become a factor in a real set of data. As far as which is better - you compare the query plans and evaluate them against whatever criteria you think is important. If the data is inconsistent, then "better" seems a stretch

Comment: @EssexSteph . . . The two methods are essentially equivalent.  I would embark on an exercise to see if the data is consistent -- and where it is not, to determine which is the better source.